# Is there a way to add displacement on top of displacement?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, shader-nodes

I'm trying to add snow on top of some mountains using the shader node version of displacement.

I've realized that plugging the displacement into the normal of another displacement just mixes both of the displacement nodes but doesn't actually add it on top of each other.

Is there a way to make the displacement of the snow go on top of the mountains displacement and furthermore the displacement of the snow also be affected by the mountains displacement?

Answer (score 0):

Use a MixRGB node to combine the displacements, You can set it to "add" or "substract" for displacement maps (black and white). I am not sure if you can displace with normal maps.

[image]
[image]